# is there a way to regenerate magento cache

Tags: magento, caching

I've built magento website but without full cache and lesti FPC cache the site is very slow, from time to time i need to clean the cache in the website to reveal changes to the catalog, is there a way to generate the cache after the cleaning except with building a basic crawler that scraps the whole website that loads every page so that next time it will be loaded from cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in a Stackoverflow thread over here: [Magento FPC Cache Warm with user groups, wget, Lesti FPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181640/magento-fpc-cache-warm-with-user-groups-wget-lesti-fpc)

I don't think you have much option other than to build your own cache warmer.  The thread highlights different types of cache you may have/need.